# REST API Naming For Different States (which are verbs)

Tags: rest, jsonschema

My team is building a REST API where there are 4 states for a particular Noun. In my case it is a `Claim`. The client would send a request to `Open` / `Update`/ `Close`/ `Re-Open` Claims.

We have different Request/Response JSON Schemas for these requests

As far as I know, have googled and taken recommendations, it's a bad practice to `add verbs to your API URLs`.

---

**Scenario 1**:: I make one POST `href = "/claim"`

Here the client would send the `Claim Status` in the `POST` request `Header` and I would parse, convert and then validate (based on `JSONSchema`) the `JSON` to `POJO` depending on what is the claim status is.

---

**Scenario 2**:: I create `4 multiple service endpoints` considering those states to be as `Nouns instead of Verbs` because the requirement is like that only.

Example: href = `"/claim/open"` `"/claim/update` etc

I want to go for `#2` because `#1` seems to be very tedious and untidy.

Also, with `#2` am not sure whether I am abiding by the convention or not.

---

**Scenario `#3`** One more thought from a colleague that can we have a request like 
`POST` `/claim` with 4 states in the body like

```
{
  'open' : {openJSON},
  'update' : {updateJSON},
  'close' : {closeJSON},
  'reopen' : {reopenJSON},
}
```

Whatever the state is, that part of `JSON` would be send by the client.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The practice of not using verbs in URIs is based on the concept that URIs identify resources.  However, It is perfectly valid for a URI to identify a script that executes some action on a resource.  That resource can be executed via the POST method.

Technically, you could write your whole API this way, but it's better if you only use this when none of the HTTP methods are sufficient.  Here is how I would do it.

**Open a claim**

`POST /claims`

Which creates a claim resource at `/claim/1234` where `1234` is the claim number.

**Update a claim**

`PUT /claim/1234` or `PATCH /claim/1234`

Essentially, the client starts with their copy of `/claim/1234`, makes the desired updates and sends the new state back to the server.

**Close a claim**

`POST /claim/1234/close`

I don't think `DELETE` is appropriate in this case because you don't want the claim to go away, you're just marking it as closed.  I would expect that `/claim/1234` has a status field indicating if it is open or closed.  Technically, you could just update that status and you wouldn't need this call at all, but for very specific updates like this I like to have a dedicated endpoint.  I think it communicates intent better.

**Re-open a claim**

`POST /claim/1234/reopen`

Again, this is a very specific update that I think deserves it's own resource in the name of expressing intent, but it's not strictly necessary.  Also, if you want to avoid verbs you can always call it `/claim/1234/reopener` instead.  It could be argued that this more effectively communicates that this is a resource that can be used to re-open a claim.

Comment: I have update the question for another set of idea. Could you please have a look into it

Comment: Scenario 3 is effectively the same as scenario 1.  You could do it, but it wouldn't be using REST very well.  I'm going to stick with my original answer.